# How to turn black and white outline of map into vector without Image Trace

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

I need a way to turn the following image into a vector in Adobe Illustrator, I have tried image trace but it never seems to do the job well enough.[image: Belgium map of cities]

Comment: You'd be far better off spending your time searching for the original vector version of that same image.

Answer (score 0):

If Image Trace doesn't work well enough for your needs then lock the layer, create a new layer, grab the pen tool and get to work. Luckily for us designers not everything is automated. If its not worth your time then you could probably purchase a vector map of Brussels or certainly contract someone to trace it for you.

I'm not sure what this map is within Brussels? Districts or something I guess? Anyways you might want to try searching for GIS / AutoCAD maps.